# Fetch all posts from group - php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, fetch

I am trying to develop a pretty simple Facebook app but I am having some difficulty with fetching all the posts from a specific group.
I know theres a lot of open thread about it but it just doesn't work for me.

Heres the code i tried to post all of the posts:

```
$access_token = $facebook ->getAccessToken();

$posts = $facebook->api('https://graph.facebook.com/[group_id]/?fields=feed.fields(message)', 'GET', $access_token);
```

And then in the html part:

```
<ul>
    <?php
         $postis = $posts['data'];
         Foreach ($postis as $post) {
                $message = idx($post, 'message');
    ?>
    <li>
         <?php echo $message; ?>
    </li>
    <?php
         }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Maybe I am mixing tons of things up together, because I already tried many times.